# Separating parallel arrays from txt file

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I'm a very novice programmer, and I'm trying to make a program that reads a txt file containing the names of 5 students (first names only) as well as four exam scores for each student. I'm trying to read the names into an array called students, then read the scores into 4 separate arrays named test1, test2, test3, test4, then display it from the monitor. The file looks like this:

> Steve 78 65 82 73
>
> Shawn 87 90 79 82
>
> Annie 92 90 89 96
>
> Carol 72 65 65 60
>
> Kathy 34 50 45 20

I'm having a very hard time with breaking up the arrays and organizing them. Can someone help me? Please keep in mind I'm very novice, so I don't know a large amount about programming.

This is my code thus far:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#define over2 "\t\t"
#define over3 "\t\t\t"
#define over4 "\t\t\t\t"
#define down5 "\n\n\n\n\n"


using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    
    ifstream inputFile;
    
    
    //Constant for max string size
    const int SIZE = 5;
     

    //Constant for the scores
    string names[SIZE], fileName, line, test1[SIZE], test2[SIZE], test3[SIZE], test4[SIZE];


    //input section, user enters their file name
    cout << down5 << down5 << over2 << "Please enter your file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    system("CLS");
    

    

    //open the file containing the responses
    inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());
     cout << endl;

    //kicks you out if file isn't found
    if (inputFile)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {  
           getline(inputFile, line);
            names[i] = line;
            getline(inputFile, line);
            test1[i] = line;
            getline(inputFile, line);
            test2[i] = line;
            getline(inputFile, line);
            test3[i] = line;
            getline(inputFile, line);
            test4[i] = line;
        }   
            inputFile.close();  
    }
    cout << down5 << over3 << "Student\tTest1\tTest2\tTest3\tTest4\n";
    cout << over3 << "-------\t-----\t-----\t-----\t-----\n";   
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << over3 << names[i] << endl;
        cout << over3 << test1[i] << endl;
        cout << over3 << test2[i] << endl;
        cout << over3 << test3[i] << endl;
        cout << over3 << test4[i] << endl;
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the structure of the file you're trying to read:

```
Steve 78 65 82 73
Shawn 87 90 79 82
Annie 92 90 89 96
Carol 72 65 65 60
Kathy 34 50 45 20
```

The format of the data can be described as follows:

- Each line represents a single "record".
- Each "record" contains multiple columns.
- Columns are separated by whitespace.

You're currently using `getline()` for every **column**:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{  
  getline(inputFile, line);
  names[i] = line;
  getline(inputFile, line);
  test1[i] = line;
  getline(inputFile, line);
  test2[i] = line;
  getline(inputFile, line);
  test3[i] = line;
  getline(inputFile, line);
  test4[i] = line;
}
```

...whereas you actually want to read in a single line for each **record** and split it up:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  string line;
  size_t start = 0;
  // For each line, attempt to read 5 columns:
  getline(inputFile, line);
  names[i] = get_column(line, start);
  test1[i] = get_column(line, start);
  test2[i] = get_column(line, start);
  test3[i] = get_column(line, start);
  test4[i] = get_column(line, start);
}
```

Here's a modified version of your original code, which splits up each line as described above:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static string get_column(string line, size_t &pos)
{
  size_t len = 0;
  // Skip any leading whitespace characters.
  while (isspace(line.c_str()[pos])) { ++pos; }
  // Count the number of non-whitespace characters that follow.
  while (!isspace(line.c_str()[pos+len]) && line.c_str()[pos+len]) { ++len; }
  // Extract those characters as a new string.
  string result = line.substr(pos, len);
  // Update the "start" position (for the next time this function is called).
  pos += len;
  // Return the string.
  return result;
}

int main()
{

  const int SIZE = 5;
  string names[SIZE], test1[SIZE], test2[SIZE], test3[SIZE], test4[SIZE];

  // Ask the user to enter a file name.
  cout << "Please enter your file name: ";
  string fileName;
  cin >> fileName;

  // Open the file and read the data.
  ifstream inputFile(fileName.c_str());
  if (!inputFile.is_open()) { return 0; }

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    string line;
    size_t start = 0;
    // For each line, attempt to read 5 columns:
    getline(inputFile, line);
    names[i] = get_column(line, start);
    test1[i] = get_column(line, start);
    test2[i] = get_column(line, start);
    test3[i] = get_column(line, start);
    test4[i] = get_column(line, start);
  }

  inputFile.close();

  // Display the data.
  cout << "Student\tTest1\tTest2\tTest3\tTest4" << endl;
  cout << "-------\t-----\t-----\t-----\t-----" << endl;

  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    cout << names[i] << "\t";
    cout << test1[i] << "\t";
    cout << test2[i] << "\t";
    cout << test3[i] << "\t";
    cout << test4[i] << endl;
  }

}
```

Running the program produces the following output:

```
Please enter your file name: textfile.txt
Student Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4
------- ----- ----- ----- -----
Steve   78    65    82    73
Shawn   87    90    79    82
Annie   92    90    89    96
Carol   72    65    65    60
Kathy   34    50    45    20
```

Note that the `get_column()` function handles multiple spaces or too-short lines, so that this file:

```
Steve 78     65 82 73
Shawn   87 90 
Annie 92 90 89 96
Carol 72 
Kathy 34 50   45 20
```

...produces the following output:

```
Please enter your file name: textfile.txt
Student Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4
------- ----- ----- ----- -----
Steve   78    65    82    73
Shawn   87    90
Annie   92    90    89    96
Carol   72
Kathy   34    50    45    20
```

Comment: When I run this function, it just outputs random numbers... why would this be? Also, I'm very very novice, so much of your get_column function makes absolutely no sense to me. :/

Comment: The `get_column()` function takes a string and a "starting point", and creates a *new* string from the first group of (non-whitespace) characters it finds after that "starting" point. If you're seeing strange results, make sure that you're setting the "start" position to `0` before calling it for the first time; the start position is updated by the `pos += len` line after that. To understand *how* it works, read up on the [`isspace()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isspace.html) function and [`substr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2119c6.aspx) method.

Comment: Also, if I wanted to calculate the average of each score and display it, what would be the simplest way to do so?

Comment: Use [`atof()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/atof.html) or [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strtod.html) to convert the strings into numbers: `double average = (atof(test1[i]) + atof(test2[i]) + atof(test3[i]) + atof(test4[i])) / 4;` Note the use of `double` rather than `int` here - integer division can lead to odd results in some cases. For example, compare the result of `3/2` (integer) versus `3.0/2.0` (floating point).

Comment: Where would I insert that into my code? and how do I declare it?

Comment: Put the code from my previous comment in the last `for()` loop (so that the `average` value is re-calculated for each user in turn) and then use `cout << average << endl;` to show the result. However, **please note that "extending" questions like this is discouraged on Stack Overflow** - you should either [edit your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29737011/edit) so that it includes *everything* you're trying to achieve, or (if that would make it [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) [post a *new* question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to this website so I wasn't aware of that. You've been incredibly helpful mate, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is overthinking the problem.

You can use your input file stream to retrieve 'formatted input' (that is, input you know to be in a format such as 'string' then 'int', 'int', 'int', 'int') with the >> operator.

```
string name;

int score[4];

ifstream mf;

mf.open("score.txt");

// Get name string.
mf >> name;

// Get four score values into an array.
mf >> score[0] >> score[1] >> score[2] >> score[3];
```

And then:

```
cout << name;

cout << score[0];
cout << score[1];
cout << score[2];
cout << score[3];
```